# Android - Convert HTML Elements From JSON Objects

Tags: java, android, html, json, xml

I have JSON object that looks like this (note: they're written in Indonesian)

[json object content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRyaB.png)

Is there any way to convert the html elements in android studio so they don't look like this? [app display with html elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BOHm.png)

I'll also put part my **java class** here just in case

```
public class Detail extends Activity {

String idkbj;
TextView backText;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
public static final String TAG_CON = "content";
private  static final String url_kbj = "https://api.url_api";

    protected String doInBackground(String... params){
        try{
            List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<>();
            params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", idkbj));
            final JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_kbj + "/" + idkbj + "/", "GET", params1);
            final JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                TextView content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content);

                    try{
                        String con_d = data.getString(TAG_CON);

                        content.setText(con_d);
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                });
    }
    catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: You should edit your question to show what you've tried and what does/does not work.

Comment: ok, I've added some part of my java class there.

honestly, I have no idea what I should write because I'm kinda new to java.

also, I change the json object code into image because stackoverflow thought it was "mostly code"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load that content in web view

```
content_web_view.loadData(content , "text/html; charset=utf-8","UTF-8");
```

or use Html.fromHtml(con_d) i.e.

```
 content.setText(Html.fromHtml(con_d));
```